# OHLC chart draw a line on from one point to another

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am developing Andrews'Pitchfork on an OHLC chart using High chart library. I have plot the graph but i am not able to find a way to draw a line on the chart. How can this be achieve.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

The graph looks like this. I have plot the graph but how to draw line does high chart gives this ability ?
[Andrew PitchFork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTD5M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use `SVGRenderer.path` function for this: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path